# CORS not working ASP.Net MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cors, actionfilterattribute

I am trying to block cross-domain access to my resources using CORS. I have tried `WebApi.Cors` and custom `ActionFilter` too. But I am still able to access the data from not allowed domains.

**My `ActionFilter` code is below**

```
public class AllowCrossSiteAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://example.com");
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
}
```

**My Controller**

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowCrossSite]
    public ActionResult Index(string username)
    {
      //return json data
    }
```

These headers are present in the response headers but why the request is not blocking from other domains, what am I doing wrong? Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the response headers will not actually provide any sort of security. Regular cors implementations only add those response headers to inform the client about the cors rules that were applied.

Something on the server needs to compare your cors rules to the `origin` / `method` etc headers of the request, and then send back a 4XX response if they don't match up.

The NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` allows you to do something like this:

`[EnableCors(origins: "https://example.com")]`

If you prefer to do your own custom implementation, you can see the source code for this attribute on [github](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http.Cors/EnableCorsAttribute.cs). That should give you a fairly good idea of what you need to do to make cors work by hand. It's simpler than it looks, really.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, any way we can prevent `CSRF` Cross-Site Request Forgery on `GET`? I am still able to forge request with required `headers` to `GET` request and getting data.

Comment: Yes, with an Authorization header and access token validation. IdentityServer3/4 is the go-to solution for that. CORS alone is not a sufficient security mechanism in that respect, it's just a first line of defense.

Comment: Thanks so much for your time, I really appreciate it. Thanks for putting me in the right direction.